# Why can't the range of this inequality parameter be determined?

Tags: equation-solving, inequalities

How can I accurately find the range of $t$? `Reduce` seems to be unable to find it:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
Reduce[{a > b > 0, a b == 1, (b/2^a)/Log[2, a + b] == t}, t, {a, b}, Reals]
(* Reduce::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the 
   methods available to Reduce. *)
```

If this is not possible, only the size relationship between $t$ and 1 would suffice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`FunctionRange`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionRange.html).

```
FunctionRange[{(b/2^a)/Log[2, a + b], a > b > 0 && a b == 1}, {a, b}, t]
(* FunctionRange::eopt: Unable to find the exact range. 
   Returning bounds on the range computed using optimization methods. *)
(* 0 <= t <= 1/2 *)
```

To remove the warning, you can manually reduce the function to a single variable:

```
FunctionRange[{(b/2^a)/Log[2, a + b], a > b > 0} /. a -> 1/b, b, t]
(* 0 < t < 1/2 *)
```

Comment: ```Clear["Global`*"]
FunctionRange[{t == Log[a, a^3 + 1] - Log[a, a^2 + 1], a > 0, 
  a != 1}, a, t]```Why cannot the value range of this function be determined using the same method?

Comment: Can you please look at the syntax of `FunctionRange` and the code I wrote before just blindly replacing some things and commenting that it doesn't work? Seriously. Why do you put in the equation `t == ...` when it needs to be just a function? `FunctionRange[{Log[a, a^3 + 1] - Log[a, a^2 + 1], a > 0 && a != 1}, a, t]`

Comment: ```In[293]:= Clear["Global`*"]
FunctionRange[{Log[a, a^3 + 1] - Log[a, a^2 + 1], a > 0, a != 1}, a, t]

Out[294]= 0 < t < 1/2 || 1/2 < t < 1```

Comment: @csn899 - or `#[{(b/2^a)/Log[2, a + b], a > b > 0, a b == 1}, {a, b}] & /@
 {MinValue, MaxValue}` evaluates to `{0, 1/2}`